# Have I done something wrong in this matrix multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q: "Take $\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{F}_{17}$. Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4\\5&6&7&8\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}1&8\\1&2\\2&0\\1&9\end{bmatrix}$. Compute $AB$ and $BA$.

A: $$AB=\begin{bmatrix}13&48\\33&124\end{bmatrix}$$ $$BA=\begin{bmatrix}41&50&59&68\\11&14&17&220\\2&4&6&8\\46&56&66&76\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm quite sure I did something wrong, but where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multiplication is correct over the integers, but in $\Bbb F_{17}$ you should reduce every element $\bmod 17$

Comment: so like, for example, it should be "$AB=\begin{bmatrix}13&14\\16&5\end{bmatrix}$"?

Comment: or should it be $AB\equiv\begin{bmatrix}13&14\\16&5\end{bmatrix}(mod 17)$

Comment: I believe the first is correct, as the elements of your field are the numbers $0$ through $16$